# How to start development with kinect

Tags: kinect

I am new to development with Kinect, so i would need some links on how could i get the development environment set up for kinect with Windows. Also once the environment is set up, could you also help me with some links on how to start up with basic programming for kinect.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start learning Kinect Development is from the samples that come along with the SDK. These samples will let you know how to do basic operations like enabling Color Stream, Skeleton Stream or Removing Background etc.

If you are totally new to Kinect Then this series will give you a Jump Start
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2

For More detailed understanding watch these Hands on Lab for Kinect.
http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/lab01/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, would start development using these.